# In Xamarin ExpandableListView, how to consume groupclick?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView where I need to consume the GroupClick and prevent the default expand/collapse actions from happening.

Using "the C# way":

```
listView.GroupClick += (s, e) =>
{
    return true;
};
```

it's not even valid, because GroupClicks are expected to be void and thus can't return true and consume the click.

If I try "the Java way" (which I would prefer not to do, but understand if it's necessary):

```
class OnGroupClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnGroupClickListener
{
    public bool OnGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View clickedView, int groupPosition, long id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("consuming groupclick");
        return true;
    }
}

// elsewhere
mylistview.SetOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener());
```

it doesn't actually do anything; the OnGroupClick never gets called.

Then, I tried disabling clicks altogether via clickable = false on the view, which is again less preferable, because I would still like to catch it and implement my own handler.  But even that doesn't seem to stop it, even if I set clickable false in both code and in the layout xml on both the expandablelistview and the header linearlayout.

There seems to be no way to make it stop expanding/collapsing on its own. What am I doing wrong? I feel like I may be missing some fundamental aspect of each way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will add a onclickEvent to any view of parent layout or parentView, then it will automatically override the default expand/collapse actions.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks.  I added rowView.SetOnClickListener in the header rows and it catches the click and prevents the default action.  Adding a rowView.Click += delegate doesn't.  Is this a bug (or more like a lack of a feature implementation) in Xamarin?

Comment: Well i am not a Xamrin developer, but i can guide you in this. Please explain your current requirement.

Comment: It is not a bug, We have similar issue in android studio too.

Comment: Nothing important, it's just that all the documentation and forums for Xamarin say "you should always use obj.Click += delegate" but I keep encountering cases like this where it's inadequate and the "Java" way must be used instead.

Comment: yup, right. We all need to customize things according to requirement. :)